# Update Register on PjSip

Tags: android, sip, pjsip

The problem is that at some point, the Register is sent again altough the port changed (TCP), the headers are not updated:

REGISTER/cseq=39874 (tdta0xad552000) to TCP 10.123.3.121:5096:

```
REGISTER sip:10.123.3.121 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 10.123.4.89:47413;rport;branch=some-branch;alias
Route: <sip:10.123.3.121:5096;transport=tcp;lr>
Max-Forwards: 70
From: <sip:%7bf6f78d85-442d-4d6f-871a-f491ddb9e005%7d@DJ-DV-TEST-V005>;tag=13bb55b7-bc11-40b6-808a-eed943a30752
To: <sip:%7bf6f78d85-442d-4d6f-871a-f491ddb9e005%7d@DJ-DV-TEST-V005>
Call-ID: 75aac0ae-45f0-4155-a893-02eafdeb257b
CSeq: 39874 REGISTER
User-Agent: Some Agent/2018-04-23 (Language=English) (OS=Android 7.0) (IP=10.123.4.89) (MAC=02:00:00:00:00:00)
Supported: outbound, path
Contact: <sip:%7bf6f78d85-442d-4d6f-871a-f491ddbagsr5%7d@10.123.4.89:47413;transport=TCP;tenantdomain=DJ-DV-TEST-V005;ob>;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:0bc37cbc-3e5e-4c8b-badb-91617a1cd37c>";reg-id=1;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000e922f243>"
Expires: 660
Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
Content-Length:  0
```

Therefore, the RPORT is different than the one in contact header (46815 - 47413):

200/REGISTER/cseq=39874 (rdata0xad41d5d8) from TCP 10.123.3.121:5096:

```
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 10.123.4.89:47413;rport=46815;received=10.123.4.89;branch=some-branch;alias
Path: <sip:10.123.3.121:64554;transport=tcp;lr>
Path: <sip:10.123.4.89:47413;transport=tcp;lr>
Contact: <sip:%7bf6f78d85-442d-4d6f-871a-f491ddb9e005%7d@10.123.4.89:47413;transport=TCP;ob;tenantdomain=DJ-DV-TEST-V005>;expires=660;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:0bc37cbc-3e5e-4c8b-badb-91617a1cd37c>";reg-id=1;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000e922f243>"
To: <sip:%7bf6f78d85-442d-4d6f-871a-f491ddb9e005%7d@DJ-DV-TEST-V005>;tag=517ac26b
From: <sip:%7bf6f78d85-442d-4d6f-871a-f491ddb9e005%7d@DJ-DV-TEST-V005>;tag=13bb55b7-bc11-40b6-808a-eed943a30752
Call-ID: 75aac0ae-45f0-4155-a893-02eafdeb257b
CSeq: 39874 REGISTER
Allow: REGISTER, INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, BYE, NOTIFY, REFER, OPTIONS, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, UPDATE
Date: Tue, 24 Apr 2018 06:39:14 GMT
User-Agent: Some Agent /11.10.0.324
Content-Length:  0
```

But the invite is not sent to the return port but to the one mentioned in contact headers, therefore the call does not work.
Unregister and register again to the server is not an option.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies with the Registrar/Proxy: it doesn't appear to work well in NAT environments.

After examining the request and response I notice the following:

- The client adds the "+sip.instance" Contact header field twice (with different values); this is incorrect.
- The client supports RFC5626, but the Registrar/Proxy doesn't. Otherwise the response would have contained a Require header field with value 'outbound' (see [RFC5626](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5626#section-4.2.1)).

As described in [RFC6314 (Best practices)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6314) the process should be as follows:

The registration will result in an outbound connection tuple being created at the Registrar/Proxy. This is used to route incoming INVITE requests to the right address.

[RFC 6314 5.1.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6314#section-5.1.1):

> [The 'reg-id' and 'sip.instance' contact header
> parameters] are used to establish an outbound connection tuple
> as defined in [RFC5626].  [...]  This ensures that any inbound request that causes
> a registration lookup will result in the reuse of the connection path
> established by the registration.  This removes the need to manipulate
> contact header URIs to represent a globally routable address as
> perceived on the public side of a NAT.

[RFC 6314 5.1.4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6314#section-5.1.4) explains how the tuple is used to route the incoming INVITE request to the right client:

> [The INVITE request] will not be forwarded to
> the address specified in the Request-URI, as standard SIP rules would
> enforce, but will be sent on the flow associated with the
> registration binding (lookup procedures in RFC 3263 [RFC3263] are
> overridden by RFC 5626 [RFC5626]).  This then allows the original
> connection/mapping from the initial registration process to be
> reused.

You should check if the Registrar/Proxy has any (other) means of NAT-support.

**Update:**

I assumed NAT is used in your network. If not, the solution is somewhat different. The INVITE request has to be sent to the port in the Contact header (47413), as is the case. This is the port the client is (should be) listening on for incoming SIP messages.

- Check if your client is indeed listening on port 47413 (for UDP/TCP, depending on the transport used for the INVITE request)
- Check if the incoming INVITE request is firewalled on your client's host